# How do you completely remove a style from bootstrap by overriding it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dom, overriding

So I'm completely familiar with overriding a style in bootstrap by using my own `Style.css`. But let's say that bootstrap has a style that is put on a table or something that is a standard html element. Let's use labels, because it's a rather short example. Let's first assume that there is no other label style or label element styling anywhere else except for the following css code:

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Now if I want to override this style in my Style.css file and change the margin and weight, I could do this:

```
label {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Easy enough, this would change those two items and allow the other styles to cascade through. But what if I wanted to completely remove any styling added by bootstrap for the element label. Is there a short and easy way to do this without having to do something like:

```
label {
  display: inline;
  max-width: None;
  color: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Or basically going through line by line and changing each styles property to something like none or normal or whatever? All while keeping the original Bootstrap file in an untouched state and not commenting anything out of it.

BTW I would also be fine with using JavaScript if it's concise and easy?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what browsers you want to support. You could use

```
label {
  all: initial; // or all: unset
}
```

but be aware that it's not really widely supported yet. It works on IE 11, Firefox, Opera & Chrome, but not Safari or most mobile browsers. Still, a good one to know if and when it becomes more widely supported :)

Comment: I'm going to try this on a test project. This is interesting.

Answer (score 2):

No if it is already include the only way to override it is to give it properties like `none`, alternatively the best way to handle it is to use their SASS/LESS implementations and not include the component at all.

Comment: Absolutely and I do use their ala carte way of loading components and I usually start a project out with all of the components commented out in SASS or in my bundle.config and only uncomment them as I need them, but I was wondering if there was a way to say "Hey, CSS I want completely remove any styles that might have been assigned to `label' element so as if it was never set in the first place" and I don't want to do it line by line.

Comment: It would be nice if there wa something like `label { !removeAll; }` or something like that lol...

Comment: That would be a bad idea for two reasons: you would have to wipe out the styles then reapply css again, very hard to maintain in the future if someone takes over your code

Comment: It looks like the only way to easily remove styles from something like bootstrap or foundation on let's say all table element based styles is to just comment it out. This way I am not going line by line and altering the styles. I would just need to document somewhere that it is being done in case we want to update the framework in the future so that we know to do it there as well. Would you say that is true?

Comment: yes since future updates will update the bootstrap.less to include everything

Comment: Hi David, did you see Joe's answer. I'm looking into that.